# C/C++ intrinsics for non-temporal loads of 32- and 64-bit values on x86_64?

Tags: c++, c, assembly, intrinsics, cpu-cache

Are there C/C++ intrinsics for non-temporal loads (i.e. loads without caching, directly from DRAM) of 32- and 64-bit values on x86_64?

My compiler is MSVC++2017 toolset v141. But intrinsics for other compilers are welcome, as well as references to the underlying assembly instructions.

Comment: What architecture are you asking for? If x86, did you have a look at [the documentation](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/)?

Comment: @fuz, it's x86_64. I had looked there: could only find non-temporal stores of 32- and 64-bit values, and non-temporal loads of 128-bit values and above.

Comment: Oh yeah, I think there are no non-temporal loads on amd64 other than that 128 bit load.

Comment: https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=temporal I see them there. for example void _mm_stream_pi (__m64* mem_addr, __m64 a)  //movntq m64, mm

Comment: @PeterJ, that's a store operation

Comment: Have you tried the instructions first? As far as I know there are any 64 & 32 bit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the time of writing (August 2017) **there are no non-temporal loads to GP registers**.

---

The only available non-temporal instructions are:

**Integer domain**

> `(v)movntdqa` **(load)** despite the name this instruction moves 128/256/512 bits, aligned on their natural boundary, into `xmm/ymm/zmm` registers respectively.
> `(v)movntdq` **(store)** despite the name this instruction moves `xmm/ymm/zmm` registers into a 128/256/512 bits, aligned on their natural boundary, memory location.

**GP registers**

> `movnti` **(store)** store a 32/64-bit GP register into a DWORD/QWORD in memory.

**MMX registers**

`movntq` **(store)** store an MMX register into a QWORD in memory.

**Floating point domain**

> `(v)movntpd/s` **(store)** **(legacy and VEX encoded)** store a `xmm/ymm/zmm` register into an aligned 128/256/512 bits memory location. Like `movntdq` but in the FP domain.
>
> `(v)movntpd/s` **(store)** **(EVEX encoded)** store a `xmm/ymm/zmm` register into an aligned 512 bits memory location clearing the upper unused bits. Like `movntdq` but in the FP domain.
> *Intel manuals are contradictory on this*

**Masked movs**

> `(v)maskmovdqu` **(store)** stores the bytes of an `xmm` register according to the mask in another `xmm` register.
>
> `(v)maskmovq` **(store)** stores the bytes of an MMX register according to the mask in another MMX register.

Comment: Intel SnB-family CPUs don't do anything with the NT hint on WB memory for `movntdqa`.  It's only special on WC memory.  AFAIK, only `prefetchNTA` does anything in practice to reduce cache pollution while reading WB memory, and I haven't tested that.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look here:
https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=temporal

```
void _mm_stream_pi (__m64* mem_addr, __m64 a)
void _mm_stream_si32 (int* mem_addr, int a)
```

and some others

and

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh977023.aspx

it is actually VS2015 documentation but the VS2017 one (at least for me) is strange, disorganised and I cant find anything there :).

for this at least as I know

```
void _mm_prefetch (char const* p, int i) is used for it.
```

those loads are short enough to only inform the uP to do not evict other data from the cache without the performance penalty (so even for non-temporal load if the there is a room in the cache it will be cached, but it will not evict any data)

Comment: These are intrinsics for *storing,* not for *loading,* as OP asked. Downvote because the answer does not answer the question.

Comment: @fuz intrinsic `_mm_prefetch` for the **prefetch**xxx instructions including `prefetchnta`

Comment: OP asked for *non temporal loads,* not *prefetches.* These two are fundamentally different operation: One loads without poisoning the cache, the other one pre-fills the cache.

Comment: @fuz I do not know any non temporal loads for DW an QW. The only way is by using `prefetchnta`. If you criticise my knowledge -  (presumably you know better) please show me any example 32 or 64bit non temporal instruction. If you do not have any examples - please stop commenting

Comment: I don't think there are any other than that one 128 non-temporal load. But providing something OP didn't ask for is just wrong.